# Error SQL7008 while updating a DB2 for iSeries table

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a Java Web application using Hibernate and DB2 for `iSeries` and during update of a table I get he following error:-

> Error SQL7008 while updating a DB2 for
>   iSeries table

Answer (score 3):

From doing some googling on this error message I noticed that it happens when you are running an insert/update in a non-transactional mode. The explanation is given [here](http://www.querytool.com/help/876.htm).

> This occurs because the table you are
>   trying to update is not being
>   journalled, and your update is being
>   run within a transaction.

Generally, you should always commit (and rollback if an exception occurs) your transactions. Usually I never set auto commit to true but in this case I would like to understand if it's truly needed as mentioned in the link above. Can you set the auto commit to `true` in your connection to see if this goes away?

`<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="true"/>`

Also this [link](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions) has some tutorials on transaction management with hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question, 
This occurs As CoolBeans mentioned because the table I was trying to update is not being journalled.

Add this table to Journal, here are the [steps](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.ii.db2udb.replication.iseries.doc/configuring/iiyrsisesetupjrnalssrc.html)

this took care of my problem.

Comment: This is way better than having external connections update a database.  Because the journal will give you a log of the database transactions including their origin