# SQL7008 Error - Workaround?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, db2, ibm-midrange

I'm using the JTOpen JDBC driver for a DB2 Universal database.  I have very little experience with SQL beyond simple statements.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388834/error-sql7008-while-updating-a-db2-for-iseries-table), I see that the error I'm getting (SQL7008) is thrown when trying to "insert/update rows in a non-journaled table during a transaction" (paraphrased).

According to the project lead, our DB is not journaled and won't be any time soon (don't ask me why, I'm not the DBA).  However, I'm working on a project where being able to `commit` everything in one go (rather than AutoCommit-ing each time an execute is called) is nearly necessary (not totally required, but it would solve a lot of issues down the road).

Is there any way to work around erorr SQL7008 without enabling Journalling?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The only way to work around it without enabling journaling is to disable **transaction isolation** in your connection string as follows:

```
jdbc:as400://systemname;naming=sql;errors=full;transaction isolation=none;date format=iso
```

The full list of JDBC properties can be found in the [IBM Toolbox for Java JDBC properties](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzahh/jdbcproperties.htm) documentation.

Comment: Do you happen to know if this URL format is supported by `AS400JDBCConnectionPoolDataSource` from the JTOpen library?

Comment: @BenCole [AS400JDBCConnection class](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzahh/jdbccon.htm): There are many optional properties that can be specified when the connection is created. Properties can be specified either as part of the URL or in a java.util.Properties object. See IBM Toolbox for Java JDBC properties for a complete list of properties supported by the AS400JDBCDriver.

Comment: This is it!  Well, kind of.  I had to set TransactionIsolation("none") in the DataSource object.

Comment: I see it's a old one but really want to get my understanding clear. By setting none to the transaction isolation, will it have any default at the database level. Cause I came across a dead lock scenario long back. The isolation level certainly helped. So let me know how much reliable and positive this suggestion !. However James mentioned it's a workaround.

Answer (score 4):

I have found that using `WITH NONE` at the end of the DB2 statement solve the problem, only if you use INSERT.

When I try using `SET OPTION COMMIT=*NONE` on a Delete statement, it seems to skip the where, and it deletes everything, the same happens when i try to use `WITH NC` or `WITH NONE`

> To resolve this issue, do one of the following:
>
> **Enable journaling for the database table:** Windows: Add a CLI Parameter 'TxnIsolation' with the value '32' within
>   your ODBC settings under "Administrative Tools". This option can be
>   found under: "Data Source" -> "Advanced Settings" -> "Add" ->
>   "TxnIsolation" as a radio button "No Commit".
>
> **AIX / Unix**: Run the following DB2 command on your database: ' db2
>   update cli cfg for section  using TXNIsolation 32'. Verify
>   these settings with the following command: ' db2 get cli cfg'
>
> **Alternate SQL workaround:** (not OS-specific): Add 'WITH NONE' to the end
>   of your SQL UPDATE command.

[More info...](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21380662)

Comment: Please quote the most relevant part of the link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

There is an option that can be added to your connection string that [disables commitment control](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzaik%2Fconnectkeywords.htm).

Probably `CommitMode=0` would work.

Comment: The *CommitMode* option is for an ODBC connection string.  The JDBC properties are not the same.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that the related Java functionality (that I know of) is `Connection.setTransactionIsolation(int level)`.  Unfortunately the related value for `CommitMode=0` is `Connection.TRANSACTION_NONE`, which is withheld with the note: `Note that Connection.TRANSACTION_NONE cannot be used because it specifies that transactions are not supported.)`

Comment: Sorry, I thought connection strings were the same.

Answer (score 0):

The official listing of SQL7008 is [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzala/rzalaml.htm) (do CTRL-F for SQL7008). It looks like you can get more information from the reason code. If you're getting reason code 3, it looks like there is no other option besides enabling journaling.

If you're getting something other than reason code 3, then I guess you have more options.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Where can I find the reason code in the SQLException being thrown?  I'm getting SQLState = 55019 and Error Code = -7008.

Comment: If you're in java looking at the SQLException is there anything in any of its other fields, like vendor code ?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems this is the only information I'm given.

Answer (score 0):

If working on CL commands. The follow command solves the issue:

```
RUNSQLSTM SRCFILE(LIBNAME/SRCFILE) SRCMBR(MBRFILE) COMMIT(*NONE) NAMING(*SQL)
```

Comment: This is for ppl who invoke scripts parked in the source machine.