# C++ DB2 Clearing a non Journal table in QTEMP

Tags: c++, sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I am developing a C++ program to fetch and filter through the data, and store it into a temporal table (P6SUBFCH) in the QTEMP library on DB2 AS400.

Reason for doing this, we using PLEX that has a defined method of fetching data in blocks of 64 records at a time, so the function called a SQLBlockFetch, fetches all the records into a temporal table, and only 64 records are returned at a time from this temporary table, and processed as such.

I am developing my own SQLBockfetch, and the C++ part of it, is using embedded SQL, to do all SQL queries. Which is fetching all the data creating the table (P6SUBFCH) in the QTEMP library.

The QTEMP library is active for a session, as soon as a session ends all tables are drops in that library.

Also to note is that all tables in QTEMP are not journaled, and from what I have researched on google is that it can't be.

**The problem**
My C++ program works great the first time it is called in a session, but the second time, it just appends the data to the previous data in the table QTEMP/P6SUBFCH. which is a problem, I tried clearing the data first (SQL DELETE statement) but I get this SQL error on the AS400 job logs.

```
Member P6SUBFCH not journaled to journal *N.
P6SUBFCH in QTEMP not valid for operation.
```

SQL ERROR:-7008

I have read the following [ql7008-error-workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232611/sql7008-error-workaround)

> To disable transaction isolation

Not sure if this is maybe my problem? I am still new to embedded SQL, not sure how I'll go about doing this.

Here is my code:

```
void LinkRepository::SaveResultsToTable(InputParameters inputParameters)
{
EXEC SQL INCLUDE SQLCA;
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
char Query2[2000] = { "" };
char Query3[2000] = { "" };

EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

strcpy(Query2, "CREATE TABLE QTEMP/P6SUBFCH");
strcat(Query2, " (PAOPIID CHAR(21) NOT NULL,");
strcat(Query2, " POPITPE CHAR(10),");
strcat(Query2, " POPISTPE CHAR(10),");
strcat(Query2, " POPIKNID CHAR(20),");
strcat(Query2, " PINSTAT CHAR(10),");
strcat(Query2, " PLEAFIND CHAR(1),");
strcat(Query2, " CLOPIID CHAR(21),");
strcat(Query2, " COPITPE CHAR(10),");
strcat(Query2, " COPISTPE CHAR(10),");
strcat(Query2, " COPIKNID CHAR(20),");
strcat(Query2, " CINSTAT CHAR(10),");
strcat(Query2, " CLEAFIND CHAR(1),");
strcat(Query2, " LINKIN CHAR(10))");

EXEC SQL EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :Query2;

// Error handling
if (sqlca.sqlcode == -601)
{
     strcpy(Query2, "DELETE FROM QTEMP/P6SUBFCH");

     EXEC SQL EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :Query2;

}

EXEC SQL COMMIT;

// Datalinks is a vector that has all the filter data to insert into the QTEMP/P6SUBFCH table
for(vector<Datalink*>::iterator dl = Datalinks.begin(); dl != Datalinks.end(); ++dl)
{
     EXEC SQL SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL NO COMMIT;

     strcpy(Query3, "INSERT INTO QTEMP/P6SUBFCH (PAOPIID,POPITPE,");
     strcat(Query3, "POPISTPE,POPIKNID,PINSTAT,PLEAFIND,");
     strcat(Query3, "CLOPIID,COPITPE,COPISTPE,COPIKNID,CINSTAT,");
     strcat(Query3, "CLEAFIND,LINKIN)");
     strcat(Query3, "VALUES('");
     strcat(Query3, (*dl)->ParentOperationsItemId);
     strcat(Query3, "','");
     strcat(Query3, (*dl)->ParentOperationsItemType);
     strcat(Query3, "','");
     strcat(Query3, (*dl)->ParentOperationsItemSubType);
     strcat(Query3, "','");
     strcat(Query3, (*dl)->ParentKnownbyId);
     strcat(Query3, "','");
     strcat(Query3, (*dl)->ParentInternalStatus);
     strcat(Query3, "','");
     append_char(Query3, (*dl)->ParentLeafIndicator);
     strcat(Query3, "','");
     strcat(Query3, (*dl)->ChildOperationsItemId);
     strcat(Query3, "','");
     strcat(Query3, (*dl)->ChildOperationsItemType);
     strcat(Query3, "','");
     strcat(Query3, (*dl)->ChildOperationsItemSubType);
     strcat(Query3, "','");
     strcat(Query3, (*dl)->ChildKnownbyId);
     strcat(Query3, "','");
     strcat(Query3, (*dl)->ChildInternalStatus);
     strcat(Query3, "','");
     append_char(Query3, (*dl)->ChildLeafIndicator);
     strcat(Query3, "','");
     strcat(Query3, (*dl)->LinkInternalStatus);
     strcat(Query3, "')");

     EXEC SQL EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :Query3;

     EXEC SQL COMMIT;
}
};
```

Comment: There may be a better solution.  Please explain why you need the temp table in the first place. What are you doing with the records once you've got them there? And how are you fetching the records in the procedure you mentioned?

Comment: We call the Blockfetch function, at least 2 times. First time it is called, it call the C++ function, to populate the temp table, and return the first 64 records, of that table. Then the second time it returns the next 64, or the next records above the first 64 block, else it returns a status, letting us know it has fetch all the records. We use theses records, for verus functions in our system. Hope this explain a little more of how we fetch data from our database.

Comment: Hopefully this means your function is doing a single SQL `FETCH FROM CURSOR x FOR 64 ROWS`, a single use of the statement brings back a block of 64 records into an array.  Suppose the SQL was able to INSERT the rows into the temp table for you directly without needing to fetch them first, even do them all in one shot rather than 64 at a time?

Comment: Then we look at what are you doing with the record in the temp table in the first place. Please explain this. Perhaps you resequence, summarize, join with another table or more. It might be that the SQL in your BlockFetch could be changed to give you the results you want, as if they had come out of the temp table. In many cases, a single SELECT can be written to do the work that would have been done in a temporary work file. You might be able to eliminate the intermediate steps of building the temp table and re-fetching data from it. IF possible, this could greatly simplify your program.

Comment: For example, if your program is reading X to put in temp table Y to insert, update, or delete on table Z, and there are no side effects (ex. other tables changed), then you can often rewrite the SQL to go from X to Z, without Y.  Temporary tables can most often be eliminated, by adding a little more logic in the original SELECT statement.  This gives the SQL optimizer the chance to decide the best way to produce the results, and it can sometimes do some pretty sophisticated processing for you under the covers.  This is especially true if the proper indexes exist.

Comment: @WarrenT I understnd what you are saying, but I don't think I can explain all the detail of our system we are developing. I will need to create my own wiki for that, but for the sake of this question, and it maybe being able to help others, I am just saying these are the parameters or rules I need to abide too. But thanks for your help, much appericated ;)

Comment: NP, I was going beyond the question.  You asked please help me do this right.  I was working on the deeper question of is it the best thing to do.  But that is a much larger question and answer than you were looking for.  When you ask the design question first, then I'll be ready ;)  My apologies.  Occupational hazard of DBA's ;)

Comment: @WarrenT Well I would like to pick your brains more, if you don't mined, is there a way I can contact you? I can also explain more about our system and would appericate your recommendations.

Comment: Sure, np.  click on my profile.        -->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I worked it out, I just added the `EXEC SQL SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL NO COMMIT;` before I called the `strcpy(Query2, "DELETE FROM QTEMP/P6SUBFCH");` query.

Here is my full code:

```
void LinkRepository::SaveResultsToTable(InputParameters inputParameters)
{
    EXEC SQL INCLUDE SQLCA;
    EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
    char Query2[2000] = { "" };
    char Query3[2000] = { "" };

    EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

    strcpy(Query2, "CREATE TABLE QTEMP/P6SUBFCH");
    strcat(Query2, " (PAOPIID CHAR(21) NOT NULL,");
    strcat(Query2, " POPITPE CHAR(10),");
    strcat(Query2, " POPISTPE CHAR(10),");
    strcat(Query2, " POPIKNID CHAR(20),");
    strcat(Query2, " PINSTAT CHAR(10),");
    strcat(Query2, " PLEAFIND CHAR(1),");
    strcat(Query2, " CLOPIID CHAR(21),");
    strcat(Query2, " COPITPE CHAR(10),");
    strcat(Query2, " COPISTPE CHAR(10),");
    strcat(Query2, " COPIKNID CHAR(20),");
    strcat(Query2, " CINSTAT CHAR(10),");
    strcat(Query2, " CLEAFIND CHAR(1),");
    strcat(Query2, " LINKIN CHAR(10))");

    EXEC SQL EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :Query2;

    // Error handling
    if (sqlca.sqlcode == -601)
    {
         EXEC SQL SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL NO COMMIT;

         strcpy(Query2, "DELETE FROM QTEMP/P6SUBFCH");

         EXEC SQL EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :Query2;

    }

    EXEC SQL COMMIT;

    // Datalinks is a vector that has all the filter data to insert into the QTEMP/P6SUBFCH table
    for(vector<Datalink*>::iterator dl = Datalinks.begin(); dl != Datalinks.end(); ++dl)
    {
         EXEC SQL SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL NO COMMIT;

         strcpy(Query3, "INSERT INTO QTEMP/P6SUBFCH (PAOPIID,POPITPE,");
         strcat(Query3, "POPISTPE,POPIKNID,PINSTAT,PLEAFIND,");
         strcat(Query3, "CLOPIID,COPITPE,COPISTPE,COPIKNID,CINSTAT,");
         strcat(Query3, "CLEAFIND,LINKIN)");
         strcat(Query3, "VALUES('");
         strcat(Query3, (*dl)->ParentOperationsItemId);
         strcat(Query3, "','");
         strcat(Query3, (*dl)->ParentOperationsItemType);
         strcat(Query3, "','");
         strcat(Query3, (*dl)->ParentOperationsItemSubType);
         strcat(Query3, "','");
         strcat(Query3, (*dl)->ParentKnownbyId);
         strcat(Query3, "','");
         strcat(Query3, (*dl)->ParentInternalStatus);
         strcat(Query3, "','");
         append_char(Query3, (*dl)->ParentLeafIndicator);
         strcat(Query3, "','");
         strcat(Query3, (*dl)->ChildOperationsItemId);
         strcat(Query3, "','");
         strcat(Query3, (*dl)->ChildOperationsItemType);
         strcat(Query3, "','");
         strcat(Query3, (*dl)->ChildOperationsItemSubType);
         strcat(Query3, "','");
         strcat(Query3, (*dl)->ChildKnownbyId);
         strcat(Query3, "','");
         strcat(Query3, (*dl)->ChildInternalStatus);
         strcat(Query3, "','");
         append_char(Query3, (*dl)->ChildLeafIndicator);
         strcat(Query3, "','");
         strcat(Query3, (*dl)->LinkInternalStatus);
         strcat(Query3, "')");

         EXEC SQL EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :Query3;

         EXEC SQL COMMIT;
    }
};
```

Comment: It would probably be better to actually add `WITH NC` to the statement.  Otherwise, you may hijack the transaction level from something else.  On that note, you should probably remove the `COMMIT` statement as well.

Comment: @ X-Zero I am not all that clued up AS400, but from what I googled the QTEMP library, is only available to the current user, in the current session, and no other users can interfere with the session being used. If I am wrong, please correct me.

Comment: Correct, QTEMP exists only within the context of that job.  No other job may access it. It is created when the job starts, and disappears when the job ends, along with its contents.  Why would you want to issue a COMMIT on a private disappearing entity?

Comment: Well, I don't see any reason why I should take it out. With this `WITH NC`, what does it do?

Comment: The `WITH NC` basically says, 'this statement doesn't care about transactions'.  This is so you wouldn't inherit the transaction level from something _else_, if a method outside of yours is running in the transaction.  I'm not worried about your QTEMP table per-se (it should be safe anyways), I'm worried about the **rest** of the running code.  Transactions are considered an overarching concern, not 'local'.  If you set the transaction level (and/or issue manual `COMMIT`s), you may cause unexpected behavior elsewhere.

Comment: @X-Zero This is the last bit of code before my function ends. But I can maybe move the commit outside the loop.