# Insert works in SQL Client but not in my code (SQL7008)

Tags: sql, hibernate, db2, sql-insert, db2-400

I am trying to perform insert/update statements in a DB2-AS400 database.
I use the jt400 driver, version 9.5 for java 8 in order to be able to connect and dialog with my DB.

In my app, I can perform selects just fine but when I try to insert or update I get the following SQL Error:

```
[SQL7008] Table not valid for operation.
```

I have done some research and it seems that it would be a journaling problem on the DB side and not in my code.

What I would like to understand is why am I able to perform insert/update using my SQL Client (DBeaver) on the same table with the exact same user ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL7008 Error - Workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232611/sql7008-error-workaround)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try disabling transaction isolation by adding `transaction isolation=none` to your connection string:

```
jdbc:as400://systemname;naming=sql;errors=full;transaction isolation=none;date format=iso
```

Ref: [SQL7008 Error - Workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232611/sql7008-error-workaround)