# Insert in data in db2 using sqlalchemy using pyodbc and iacces

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, db2, odbc

I'm trying to insert some data on a DB2 table on an IBM iSeries (AS400) server, using `sqlalchemy`, `pyodbc` and the `iaccess` packages.

The server allows me to run `SELECT` and `CREATE` queries, but when I try to insert rows i get the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY000', "[*REDACTED*]
> SQL7008 - TABLE in DATABASE not valid for operations. (-7008)
> (SQLExecDirectW)")

I'm executing the following query

```
INSERT INTO database.table VALUES ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

I know the query works because I am able to run it using the same credentials from Aqua data studio, a db management IDE.

I'm using the following python code to connect to the db:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd


engine_statement = f"iaccess+pyodbc://{user}:{pwd}@{server}/{schema_name}?DRIVER={driver}"

connection = create_engine(engine_statement)
```

I tried using `ibmi` instead of `iaccess+pyodbc` but nothing changes.

The closest queztion I found [asks the same thing but using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66748828/as400-db2-sql7008-table-name-not-valid-for-operations-when-inserting-a-record).

I tried implementing the answer there in python, by setting the `isolation_level` option to all possible values, but still nothing changes.

I'm not 100% sure how journaling works and therefore how to use it so I was not able to implement point 2 in the answer.

If it may help, I am able to create new tables, but not write on them, which seems surprising, but I'm no sql expert so I guess I'm missing something.

Comment: have you tried using https://pypi.org/project/ibm-db-sa/ ?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention, I was not able to install it on the machine I'm using

Comment: Try with autocommit = true option on database connection

Comment: Yeah I also tried that and it doesn't work

Comment: I'm currently struggling with the exact same problem and error message.
Using the ibmi also but I'm struggling to insert any data into a newly created table.
Creating the table itself seems to work somehow but then crashes as soon as the INSERT INTO statement is being executed. 
Have you any solution for this by any chance? I read setting the isolation level to none would be workaround but unfortunately ibmi isn't supporting this option, yet.

Comment: I ended up using [`pyodbc.connect`](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc) with the `{iSeries Access ODBC Driver}`  driver, with the autocommit parameter set to True (didn't work otherwise). I was not able to make sqlalchemy work, which makes me a bit sad.