How to disable autocomit with ibm db2 for i in SqlAlchemy
How do i turn off autocommit with ibm_db_sa and sqlalchemy?
If the table has journaling on, this is not required, but this one table does not have journaling on, as such, autocommit must be OFF.
I have tried:
smt = f"db2+ibm_db://{user}:{password}@{hostname}:{port}/{database};autocommit=0"

engine = create_engine(smt, echo=True).execution_options(autocommit=False)

sm = sessionmaker(engine, autocommit=False, autoflush=False)

with sm.begin() as session:
    record = User(**user_dict)
    session.add(record)


but i get:
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ibm_db_dbi.ProgrammingError) ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError: Statement Execute Failed: [IBM][CLI Driver][AS] SQL7008N  REXX variable "USERSG     " contains inconsistent data.  SQLSTATE=55019 SQLCODE=-7008
JBDC connector has autocommit off and it works.
EDIT: setting autocommit=True gives the same error.
I have tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/8245270/9544507  and this Entity Framework error updating iSeries record they recommend disabbling the autocomit mode, but does not seem to work.
I have also tried to set isolation_level to AUTOCOMMIT and NONE (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#understanding-the-dbapi-level-autocommit-isolation-level)
But that does not work either:
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Invalid value 'AUTOCOMMIT' for isolation_level. Valid isolation levels for ibm_db_sa are RS, UR, CURSOR STABILITY, RR, UNCOMMITTED READ, READ STABILITY, CS, REPEATABLE READ

What version of sqlalchemy are you using?

latest version 2.0.29 and python 3.10

I know very little about this but have you confirmed that the ibm_db driver works directly without the sqlalchemy integration?  Also I didn't know much about this driver and dialect before but it looks pretty rare.  It might not have Sqlalchemy 2+ support.  Maybe try 1.4.* sqlalchemy series and see if that has any affect.

Maybe try using this method of passing args: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#use-the-connect-args-dictionary-parameter

I'm a bit confused. The long-standing behaviour of SQLAlchemy is to have autocommit OFF by default, in conformance with the DBAPI_2.0 spec. Users who want autocommit ON have to explicitly enable it. You call create_engine(…, echo=True) so what do your logs show? If autocommit is OFF you should see BEGIN (implicit) followed by INSERT INTO …. If autocommit is ON you should see BEGIN (implicit; DBAPI should not BEGIN due to autocommit mode) followed by INSERT INTO …

It almost looks like you can't use isolation level none with sqlalchemy. I don't expect turning autocommit off would change the isolation level. Your only option may be to start journaling on those files.

I'm just putting this in an answer so I don't stuff it in the comments.  But maybe try this usage.
import ibm_db

connect_args = { 
    ibm_db.SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT: ibm_db.SQL_AUTOCOMMIT_OFF,
}

smt = f"db2+ibm_db://{user}:{password}@{hostname}:{port}/{database}"

engine = create_engine(smt, 
    echo=True,
    connect_args=connect_args
)

